# How to populate select option using api

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is my code. I am getting **student's** data from backed, filtering it.
I am not able to set the default value for the select option and neither is `setAssignedStudent` working, in the console, I am getting `undefined`. Please let me know how to fix this.

```
//here is sample of students array
// let students- [  {name: "abc", email:"abc.com", mentor:"" },  
// {name: "abc", email:"abc.com", mentor:"cda" },  {name: "abc", email:"abc.com", //mentor:"" }]
useEffect(() => {
    const getStudents = async () => {
      try {
        const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/students");
        const data = await res.json();
        //console.log(data);
        //filtering students based on who doesn;t have mentor
        let filter = data.filter((e) => {
          return e.mentor === "";
        });
        if (filter.length > 0) setStudents(filter);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };
    getStudents();
  }, []);
 const [assignedStudent, setAssignedStudent] = useState(students[1]);
 const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAssignedStudent(
      students.find((student) => student._id == e.target.value)
    );
    console.log(assignedStudent);
  };
 const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
 console.log(assignedStudent);
}

<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e)}>
          <select onChange={handleChange} value={assignedStudent}>
            {students.map((student) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <option key={student._id} value={student.id}>
                    {student.name}
                  </option>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </select>
          <button type="submit">Submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### The Problem:

your **students** object is empty before the API call and was not initialized in your `setState`. so using `students.map` in your `select` element will cause the error (since you can't map through an undefined array).

##### The Solution:

There are two important things before using the `map` with **arrayes**:

1. check for the **definition** of the array (is the array defined and exists?)
2. check its **length** (is the array has some content?)

#### First

check its declaration/definition by a simple `if` statement:

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData) {
    myArrayOfData.map(
      // rest of the codes ...
    )
  }
}
```

Or with using `?` shorthanded of `if`

```
{
  myArrayOfData?.map(
    // rest of the codes ...
  )
}
```

#### Second

check for the contents of the array and use the `map` function after checking its **length** (which tells you the data has arrived from the API call etc. and is ready to process)

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData) {
    if(myArrayOfData.length > 0) {
     myArrayOfData.map(
        // rest of the codes ...
     )
    }
  }
}
```

#### Finally:

while the above snippet works properly, you can simplify it by checking both `if` conditions together:

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData?.length > 0) {
     myArrayOfData.map(
        // rest of the codes ...
     )
  }
}
```

##### Optional:

In real-world examples, you may need to show some loading components while the data is fetching.

```
{
  if(myArrayOfData?.length > 0) {
    myArrayOfData.map(
      // rest of the codes ...
    )
  } else {
    <Loading />
  }
}
```

###### Be Aware

```
const anEmptyArray  = []

if(anEmptyArray){
  // rest of the codes ...
}
```

The result of comparison on `if(anEmptyArray)` is always `true` with an empty array.

Answer (score 2):

The option value should be _id. In your find you are comparing with `student._id` but in the option the value props you passed is `student.id` that's why find returns undefined

```
<option key={student._id} value={student._id} 
   {student.name}
</option>
```

Comment: I thought the problem was _id? @Zed