# I got undefined data while getting it from useSelector in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

I am making an e commerce website for which , I am using react and redux for frontend and express as the server . I got undefined when I tried to access the data of the redux store from useSelector hook , but I got the data when I console.log() it in the action . Please help I have been struggling with this from the last two days.

I am getting this error : TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

This is My code for HomeScreen

```
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList);
const { products } = productList;
console.log("Product List : ", products);

useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(listProducts());
}, [dispatch]);

return (
 <div>
   {products.map((data, id) => {
     return (
       <div className="product_div" key={id}>
         <Products data={data} />
       </div>
     );
   })}
 </div>
```

);

This is For productAction:

```
import {
 PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE,
 PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST,
 PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS,
} from "../Constants/productConstants";

export const listProducts = () => async (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST });
 try {
  const res = await fetch("/products", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "Application/Json",
    },
  });
const data = await res.json();
console.log("Product Data : ", data);
dispatch({ type: PRODUCT_LIST_SUCCESS, payload: data });
} catch (error) {
  dispatch({ PRODUCT_LIST_FAILURE, payload: error });
}
```

};

**I got the data here **

But it shows porducts as undefined in HomeScreen.js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to populate select option using api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69416179/how-to-populate-select-option-using-api)

Comment: take a look at the accepted answer. your problem is as same. your "products" array is an empty array on initializing or is undefined before API calls, so mapping causes the problem. you can simply fix it by checking the length of your products before mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tro to add an undefined check in the `HomeScreen` component and return a loading message in it.
This should avoid causing a crash in your application, and will render the data once they are ready.

```
...

if (!products) {
    return <div>Loading products...</div>
}

return (
 <div>
   {products.map((data, id) => {
     return (
       <div className="product_div" key={id}>
         <Products data={data} />
       </div>
     );
   })}
 </div>
```